# Black screen when waking up from suspend when using 960M GTX graphics card

Tags: 16.04, kernel, suspend, 16.10

My laptop is UX510UW Asus. It has 960M GTX and Intel® HD Graphics 520. When I use Intel GPU then everything goes fine; I have no problem when I wake up from suspend. But when I switch to 960M GTX then I cannot wake up from suspend; I get a black screen when I try to wake up from hibernation and I need to press the power button my laptop to restart. I have tried

- Upgrading to newest driver.
- `pm-suspend` to debug. But I only get a black screen.

My current driver is 4.8.3-040803-generic - Ubuntu 16.10.

What should I do?

Originally I installed 16.04, and I had this issue. I tried different methods to fix it without success, so I upgraded to 16.10 and the problem persists.

Comment: Edit your `/etc/default/grub` and add `nomodeset` to the `Linux` argument.  Add this to the line that says `quiet splash`.

Comment: @L.D.James no working :(

Comment: When you added this option, did you run `sudo update-grub`, then reboot after the update?

Comment: @L.D.James yes i did but the problem is , when i restart and update-grub ..   the system does not render any video graphic driver anymore ...